# My code won't run for some values of range() in a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, range

I created a small game where the computer is supposed to guess the number I choose (between 1 and 100). To make it more efficient, I made it so that its first guess is always 50, and then it tries to guess it by guessing the midpoint between his last guess and the "higher" or "lower" number he can guess (I know, not really a good explanation, but you'll see the code just below).

Anyway, I noticed that it would always get to the answer in a maximum of 7 tries, at least in the case of the few numbers I chose. So, to test that hypothesis, I wrote the code below:

```
def take_guess(lower, higher):
    return lower + (higher - lower)/2

lower = 0
higher = 100
t = 1
l = []

for i in range(1,100):
    while True:
        guess = take_guess(lower, higher)
        if guess == i:
            l.append(t)
            t = 1
            break
        elif guess > i:
            higher = guess
            t += 1
            continue
        elif guess < i:
            lower = guess
            t += 1
            continue

print sorted(l)[-1]
```

The problem is, it will only run with range(1,2) or range(1,3). Any bigger range and it just won't run. Is there any reason why?

Comment: Printing i, guess, lower, higher at every loop iteration would have caught the bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is pretty much right. You just forgot to reset the values of `higher` and `lower` when you increment `i`.

Here is a working version of your code (for Python 2)

```
def take_guess(lower, higher):
    return lower + (higher - lower)/2

lower = 0
higher = 100
t = 1
l = []

for i in range(1,100):
    ###########################
    # This is the only change!
    lower = 0
    higher = 100
    ###########################

    while True:
        # You can watch exactly what's happening by uncommenting the following line:
        # print("i={}\t lower={}\t higher={}".format(i, lower, higher))
        guess = take_guess(lower, higher)
        if guess == i:
            l.append(t)
            t = 1
            break
        elif guess > i:
            higher = guess
            t += 1
            continue
        elif guess < i:
            lower = guess
            t += 1
            continue

print sorted(l)[-1]
```

Comment: Well, that's the most complete answer so far. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

When the value of i becomes 3,  the value of lower = 1 and higher = 3, so guess =2. Now as guess is less than i , guess=lower=2. However, guess is still 2 as 2+ 1/2 = 2 , so it goes to infinite loop as value of guess never changes , that is guess < i and you are stuck in same condition as guess is always 2 and i  is always 3.

Comment: Yeah, that was exactly the problem. I just had to reset higher and lower every time I guess the number correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is also comparing the guess to i. Let's follow it through the loop:

first guess = 50; i = 1

second guess = 25; i = 2

third guess = 12.5; i = 3

At this point, the guess stops being an integer and it won't ever match.

You should probably be defining the number it is guessing first, or by setting it to a random number try:

```
import random
answer = random.randint(1,100)
```

Comment: This is not the problem. The problem is that he never resets the values of `higher` and `lower` when he increments `i`.

Answer (score -1):

This works - Please note the Upper and Lower values are reset in the function definition.

```
def take_guess(lower, higher):
    return int(lower + (higher - lower) / 2)


def calc_guesses(i):
    lower = 0
    higher = 100
    t = 1
    while True:
        guess = take_guess(lower, higher)
        #print("i is {}  guess is {}".format(i,guess))
        if guess == i:
            l.append(t)
            t = 1
            break
        elif guess > i:
            higher = guess
            t += 1
            continue
        elif guess < i:
            lower = guess
            t += 1
            continue
    return t



l = []
for i in range(1,100):
    l.append(calc_guesses(i))

l.sort()
print ("Last value is {}".format(l[-1]))
```

Output

```
7
```

Regards

Comment: This is not the problem. The problem is that he never resets the values of `higher` and `lower` when he increments `i`.

Comment: Please look at the code I supplied  !!! It is initialized each time the function is called.

Comment: You are correct! I didn't notice that you had wrapped it in a function! I retract my downvote.

Comment: It won't let me change my vote unless you edit the post. Perhaps you could remove the part where it says the problem is due to fractional division, because the problem was not ultimately to do with that.